# AffineTransform.rotate() - how do I xlate, rotate, and scale at the same time?

Tags: java, graphics, awt, image-rotation, affinetransform

I have the following code which does (the first part of) what I want drawing a chessboard with some pieces on it.

```
              Image pieceImage = getImage(currentPiece);
              int pieceHeight = pieceImage.getHeight(null);
              double scale = (double)side/(double)pieceHeight;
              AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
              transform.setToTranslation(xPos, yPos);
              transform.scale(scale, scale);
              realGraphics.drawImage(pieceImage, transform, this);
```

that is, it gets a chess piece's image and the image's height, it translates the drawing of that image to the square the piece is on and scales the image to the size of the square.

Llet's say I want to rotate the black pieces 180 degrees.  Somewhere I expect to have something like:

```
transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(180) /* ?, ? */);
```

But I can't figure out what to put in as X and Y.  If I put nothing, the image is nicely rotated around the 0,0 point of its chessboard square, putting the piece upside down in the square to the northeast of where it is supposed to be.  I've guessed at various other combinations of x,y, with no luck yet.

I am already using translation to put the piece in the right square, the rotation transform wants another x,y around which to rotate things, but I don't know how to tell the transform to rotate the piece around one x,y and write the image to a different x,y.  Can someone help me with the rotation parameters, or point me to something that explains how these things work?  I've found examples of things that don't explain how they work, and so far I haven't figured out how to alter them to my situation...

---

Major edit: addition of working code.  Sorry, I don't know how to post images, please substitute your own.

When I run the following I get a 2x2 chess board with a rook at the top left and a knight at the bottom right.

If I go into SmallChessboardComponent and take the comment delims off the first rotation transform statement, I get the rook in its original place upside down and the knight does not appear.  If I *instead* take the comment delims off the second transform statement, neither piece appears at all.

I am looking for a way to turn the pieces upside down on the square on which they would appear anyway.  I want to draw each piece onto the board; I don't want code that flips the board.

main program:

```
package main;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import directredraw.SmallChessboardComponent;

public class SmallChessboardMain
{
  private static void dbg (String message) { System.out.println(message); }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    //Create the top-level container and add contents to it.
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Small Chessboard");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // create the chessboard itself and set it in the component
    SmallChessboard chessboard = new SmallChessboard();

    // create the GUI component that will contain the chessboard
    SmallChessboardComponent chessboardComponent = new SmallChessboardComponent();
    chessboardComponent.setBoard (chessboard);

    frame.getContentPane().add(chessboardComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // pack and display all this
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

chessboard class:

```
package main;

public class SmallChessboard
{
  Piece [][] squares = new Piece[2][2];

  public SmallChessboard()
  {
    squares[0][0] = new Piece(Piece.WHITECOLOR, Piece.ROOK);
    squares[1][1] = new Piece(Piece.WHITECOLOR, Piece.KNIGHT);
  }

  /**
   * get the piece at the given rank and file; null if
   * no piece exists there.
   */
  public Piece getPiece(int rank, int file)
  { 
    if (0 > rank || rank > 2 || 0 > file || file > 2) { return null; }
      else { return squares[rank][file]; }
  }
}
```

chessboard component class:

```
package directredraw;


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import main.Piece;
import main.PieceImages;
import main.SmallChessboard;


public class SmallChessboardComponent extends JPanel
  { 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Color whiteSquareColor = Color.yellow;
    Color blackSquareColor = Color.blue;

    private static void dbg (String msg) { System.out.println(msg); }

    private SmallChessboard  chessboard = null;

    // currently playing with rotating images; this affine transform
    // should help
    AffineTransform rotationTransform = null;

    private final int DEFAULT_PREFERRED_SIDE = 400;
    int wholeSide = DEFAULT_PREFERRED_SIDE;
    int side = DEFAULT_PREFERRED_SIDE / 8;

    public void setBoard (SmallChessboard givenBoard)
    { chessboard = givenBoard;
    }

    /**
     * set either or both colors for this chessboard; if either of
     * the arguments are null, they do not change the existing color
     * setting.
     */
    public void setColors (Color darkSquare, Color lightSquare)
    {
      if (darkSquare != null) { blackSquareColor = darkSquare; }
      if (lightSquare != null) { whiteSquareColor = lightSquare; }
    }

    /**
     * return the preferred size for this component.s
     */
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    { return new Dimension(wholeSide, wholeSide);
    }

    /*
     * return the image object for the given piece
     */
    private Image getImage(Piece piece)
    { return PieceImages.getPieceImage(this, piece);
    }

    public void paintComponent (Graphics graphics)
    {
      Graphics2D realGraphics = (Graphics2D) graphics;

      // the image container might have been stretched.
      // calculate the largest square held by the current container,
      // and then 1/2 of that size for an individual square.
      int wholeWidth  = this.getWidth();
      int wholeHeight = this.getHeight();
      wholeSide   = (wholeWidth / 2) * 2;
      if (wholeHeight < wholeWidth) { wholeSide = (wholeHeight / 2) * 2; }
      side = wholeSide / 2; 

      Rectangle clip = realGraphics.getClipBounds();
      boolean firstColumnWhite = false;

      // for each file on the board:
      //    set whether top square is white
      //    set background color according to white/black square
      //    
      for (int fileIndex=0; fileIndex<8; fileIndex++)
        { boolean currentColorWhite = firstColumnWhite;
          firstColumnWhite = !firstColumnWhite;

          // draw the board and all the pieces
          int rankIndex = 2;
          for (rankIndex=2; rankIndex>=0; rankIndex--)
          { 

            currentColorWhite = !currentColorWhite;

            // x and y position of the top left corner of the square we're drawing,
            // and rect becomes the dimensions and position of the square itself.
            int xPos = fileIndex * side;
            int yPos = rankIndex * side;
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, side, side);

            // if this square intersects the clipping rectangle we're drawing,
            // then we'll draw the square and the piece on the square.
            if (rect.intersects(clip))
            {
              // this puts down the correct color of square 
              if (currentColorWhite) { realGraphics.setColor(whiteSquareColor); }
                                else { realGraphics.setColor(blackSquareColor); }
              realGraphics.fillRect(xPos, yPos, side, side); 

              // if there is a piece on this square and it isn't selected at the
              // moment, then draw it.
              Piece currentPiece = chessboard.getPiece(rankIndex, fileIndex);
              if (currentPiece != null)
                { 
                  Image pieceImage = getImage(currentPiece);
                  int pieceHeight = pieceImage.getHeight(null);
                  double scalePiece = (double)side/(double)pieceHeight;
                  AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
//                  transform.setToRotation(Math.toRadians(180));
                  transform.setToRotation(Math.toRadians(180), side/2, side/2);
                  transform.scale(scalePiece, scalePiece);
                  transform.translate(xPos/scalePiece, yPos/scalePiece);
//                  if (currentPiece.isBlack()) 
//                  {
//                    transform.translate(xPos + (side+2), yPos + (side+2));
//                    transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(180) /*, ,*/ ); 
//                  }
//                  else
//                  {
//                    transform.translate(xPos, yPos);
//                  }
                  realGraphics.drawImage(pieceImage, transform, this);
                }
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
```

Piece.java

```
package main;

public class Piece
{ 
  // piece types; the sum of the piece type and the
  // color gives a number unique to both type and color,
  // which is used for things like image indices.
  public static final int PAWN   = 0;
  public static final int KNIGHT = 1;
  public static final int BISHOP = 2;
  public static final int ROOK   = 3;
  public static final int QUEEN  = 4;
  public static final int KING   = 5;

  // one of these is the color of the current piece
  public static final int NOCOLOR = -1;
  // the sum of the piece type and the
  // color gives a number unique to both type and color,
  // which is used for things like image indices.
  public static final int BLACKCOLOR = 0;
  public static final int WHITECOLOR = 6;

  int color = NOCOLOR;
  int imageIndex;

  public Piece(int color, int pieceType)
  { 
    // dbg -- all pieces are white rooks for now...
    this.color  = color;
    imageIndex  = color + pieceType;
  }

  /**
   * return the integer associated with this piece's color;
   */
  int getPieceColor()
  { return color;
  }

  /**
   * return true if the piece is black
   */
  public boolean isBlack() 
  { 
    return (color == BLACKCOLOR); 
  }

  /**
   * set the color associated with this piece; constants
   * found in this class.
   */
  public void setPieceColor(int givenColor)
  { color = givenColor;
  }

  /**
   * return the integer designated for the image used for this piece.
   */
  int getImageIndex()
  { return imageIndex;
  }

}
```

and PieceImages.java

```
package main;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MediaTracker;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.net.URL;

public class PieceImages
{ static Image images[] = null;

private static void dbg (String msg) { System.out.println(msg); } 

  public static Image getPieceImage (Component target, Piece piece)
  {
    if (images == null)
    try
    { 
      MediaTracker tracker = new MediaTracker(target);
      images = new Image[12];
      images[Piece.BLACKCOLOR + Piece.PAWN] = getImage(tracker, "bPawn.gif");
      images[Piece.BLACKCOLOR + Piece.KNIGHT] = getImage(tracker, "bKnight.gif");
      images[Piece.BLACKCOLOR + Piece.BISHOP] = getImage(tracker, "bBishop.gif");
      images[Piece.BLACKCOLOR + Piece.ROOK] = getImage(tracker, "bRook.gif");
      images[Piece.BLACKCOLOR + Piece.QUEEN] = getImage(tracker, "bQueen.gif");
      images[Piece.BLACKCOLOR + Piece.KING] = getImage(tracker, "bKing.gif");

      images[Piece.WHITECOLOR + Piece.PAWN] = getImage(tracker, "wPawn.gif");
      images[Piece.WHITECOLOR + Piece.KNIGHT] = getImage(tracker, "wKnight.gif");
      images[Piece.WHITECOLOR + Piece.BISHOP] = getImage(tracker, "wBishop.gif");
      images[Piece.WHITECOLOR + Piece.ROOK] = getImage(tracker, "wRook.gif");
      images[Piece.WHITECOLOR + Piece.QUEEN] = getImage(tracker, "wQueen.gif");
      images[Piece.WHITECOLOR + Piece.KING] = getImage(tracker, "wKing.gif");
      if (!tracker.waitForAll(10000))
      { System.out.println("ERROR: not all piece main.images loaded");
      }
      dbg("piece images loaded");
    }
    catch (Exception xcp)
    { System.out.println("Error loading images");
      xcp.printStackTrace();
    }
    return images[piece.getImageIndex()];
  }

  private static Image getImage(MediaTracker tracker, String file)
  {
    URL url = PieceImages.class.getResource("images/" + file);
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);
    tracker.addImage(image,  1);
    return image;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, this is a little slight of hand.  The example code will only work for 90 degree increments (it was only designed this way), to do smaller increments you to use some trig to calculate the image width and height (there's a answer somewhere for that to ;))

```
public class ImagePane extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage masterImage;
    private BufferedImage renderedImage;

    public ImagePane(BufferedImage image) {
        masterImage = image;
        applyRotation(0);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(renderedImage.getWidth(), renderedImage.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return getPreferredSize();
    }

    protected int getVirtualAngle(int angle) {
        float fRotations = (float) angle / 360f;
        int rotations = (int) (fRotations - (fRotations / 1000));

        int virtual = angle - (rotations * 360);

        if (virtual < 0) {
            virtual = 360 + virtual;
        }

        return virtual;
    }

    public void applyRotation(int angle) {
        // This will only work for angles of 90 degrees...

        // Normalize the angle to make sure it's only between 0-360 degrees
        int virtualAngle = getVirtualAngle(angle);
        Dimension size = new Dimension(masterImage.getWidth(), masterImage.getHeight());
        int masterWidth = masterImage.getWidth();
        int masterHeight = masterImage.getHeight();

        double x = 0; //masterWidth / 2.0;
        double y = 0; //masterHeight / 2.0;

        switch (virtualAngle) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 180:
                break;
            case 90:
            case 270:
                size = new Dimension(masterImage.getHeight(), masterImage.getWidth());
                x = (masterHeight - masterWidth) / 2.0;
                y = (masterWidth - masterHeight) / 2.0;
                break;
        }
        renderedImage = new BufferedImage(size.width, size.height, masterImage.getTransparency());
        Graphics2D g2d = renderedImage.createGraphics();

        AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y);

        at.rotate(Math.toRadians(virtualAngle), masterWidth / 2.0, masterHeight / 2.0);
        g2d.drawImage(masterImage, at, null);

        g2d.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        int width = getWidth() - 1;
        int height = getHeight() - 1;

        int x = (width - renderedImage.getWidth()) / 2;
        int y = (height - renderedImage.getHeight()) / 2;

        g2d.drawImage(renderedImage, x, y, this);
    }

}
```

Now, you could simply "flip" the image vertically, if that works better for you

```
public class FlipPane extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage masterImage;
    private BufferedImage renderedImage;

    public FlipPane(BufferedImage image) {
        masterImage = image;
        flipMaster();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(renderedImage.getWidth(), renderedImage.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return getPreferredSize();
    }

    protected void flipMaster() {
        renderedImage = new BufferedImage(masterImage.getWidth(), masterImage.getHeight(), masterImage.getTransparency());
        Graphics2D g2d = renderedImage.createGraphics();
        g2d.setTransform(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(1, -1));
        g2d.drawImage(masterImage, 0, -masterImage.getHeight(), this);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        int width = getWidth() - 1;
        int height = getHeight() - 1;

        int x = (width - renderedImage.getWidth()) / 2;
        int y = (height - renderedImage.getHeight()) / 2;

        g2d.drawImage(renderedImage, x, y, this);
    }
}
```

This basically results in:

[image: Image rotation example]

Original | 180 degree rotation | Vertical inversion...

Now, if you change the `flipMaster` method to read:

```
g2d.setTransform(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(-1, -1));
g2d.drawImage(masterImage, -masterImage.getWidth(), -masterImage.getHeight(), this);
```

You'll get the same effect as the 180 rotation ;)

Comment: I'm REALLY hoping for a less involved solution, something involving a transform that I can put into the existing code without doubling it.  I haven't evaluated this fully, but will do so when I have more time.  In the meanwhile I've added a working example to the original question.

Comment: The 3 lines it took to "flip" the images is probably the easiest of the two solutions, assuming you only want to rotate it 180 degrees

Comment: You led me to what I'm going to do -- I wish I knew more about this, must look up a decent overall tutorial on image rendering or something, wish it were easier to find.  I've now got code that will flip just the image; I'll call that separately, and then translate and scale it in a different operation.  I still think there may be some way to do what I was originally trying to do, but I guess I've satisfied myself that it isn't obvious to fellow posters.  Now, if you'll just post a comment telling me how to put images in my answers, I'll be all set  8>).

Comment: @rcook I know the feeling :P - Personally, I'd scale the images first, espically if they only need to remain at a constant size.  It will make the translation and rotation matrix simpler and the memory required to perform the operation less...IMHO

Answer (score 2):

Try performing the rotation before translating it into the correct position. Simply reorder the transformations so that first you scale, then you rotate (around the center point of the image), and then you translate:

```
transform.scale(scale, scale);
transform.rotate(Math.PI, pieceWidth / 2, pieceHeight /2);
transform.translation(xPos, yPos);
```

By the way, the black pieces on a chess board usually aren't rotated. :)

**Update**

In what way does it not work? The solution I provided also also differs from your code in that scaling is performed before translating. You can try the rotating, translating, and then scaling.

I strongly suggest that you modify your code so that you can perform the translation last. If you do this, everything will become a lot less complicated. Once you have done so, you only have to scale once to automatically take care of the rotation.

```
transform.scale(scale, scale); // or transform.scale(scale, -scale); to rotate
transform.translate(xPos, yPos);
```

Comment: Interesting, but it doesn't work -- evidently an SSCE is necessary, I am editing the original question to post all 400-odd lines of code.

Comment: To begin with, as near as I can tell from the javadoc and trial-and-error, doing "setToTranslation" wipes out the effect of the scale and rotate, so what you have does not scale or rotate the image.  If I do 'scale, rotate, translate', my white rook (in the SSCE) does not appear, and the knight appears in the very center of the board, not on any square.  It's as if it (they) got rotated but not around their own center point.  That's what I don't understand about this whole thing, and my original question -- what is that x,y position supposed to be in this case?