# How to select a figure to move, rotate and scale with Java2D

Tags: java, java-2d

I have problems that are not as selecting a figure and that figure selected apply a rotation as many figures as I do not do the following as the first two points and I have but not the third:

- The program should allow multiple draw figures in the plane.
- Each time you insert a figure in the plane should ask the dimensions of the figure and the coordinates in the insertion.
- Once inserted the figure the program should allow the selected shape transformations, rotations, translations and scaling.

Comment: and tried to addMouseListener but not as to select the object rotate or scale it if you need my code public.

Comment: Wha? your latest comment makes little sense. I don't think you've provided nearly enough information for this question to be answerable.

Answer (score 0):

You've not provided enough details about your problem, but, you can take a look at the following that deal with rotation

- [AffineTransform.rotate() - how do I xlate, rotate, and scale at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911610/affinetransform-rotate-how-do-i-xlate-rotate-and-scale-at-the-same-time/11911758#11911758)
- [How to mirror an image with Java.awt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432791/how-to-mirror-an-image-with-java-awt/12433025#12433025)
- [Change the angle/position of a drawing with a algorithm in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824684/change-the-angle-position-of-a-drawing-with-a-algorithm-in-java/12826882#12826882)

The following deal with resizing

- [How do I resize images inside an application when the application window is resized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876615/how-do-i-resize-images-inside-an-application-when-the-application-window-is-resi/12876799#12876799)
- [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928)

I also suggest you take a look through

- [Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Using Mouse Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)