# How do I flip an image to the right using AffineTransform in Java?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, affinetransform

I have the flip left functionality down (see code below) but I can't seem to find how to do a flip right. Are the calculations similar?

Flip Left:

```
{
    gb.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    gb.dispose();

    AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
    tx.translate(img.getHeight(null) / 2, img.getWidth(null) / 2);
    tx.rotate(Math.PI / 2);

    tx.translate(-img.getHeight(null) / 2, -img.getWidth(null) / 2);
    AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);

    buffImg = op.filter(buffImg, null);
 }
```

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275424/rotating-image-with-affinetransform/20280225#20280225)?

Comment: Or something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824684/change-the-angle-position-of-a-drawing-with-a-algorithm-in-java/12826882#12826882)

Comment: Second example helped a lot! thanks @MadProgrammer

Comment: I was looking for another example which would resize the image based on the angel of rotation, when I realised that the first example actually does that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate in multiples of 90 degrees left or right, you could use the [AffineTransform.getQuadrantRotateInstance(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#getQuadrantRotateInstance(int)) methods instead:

```
AffineTransform rotateLeft = AffineTransform.getQuadrantRotateInstance(1);
AffineTransform rotateRight = AffineTransform.getQuadrantRotateInstance(-1);
```

There's also anchored versions:

```
AffineTransform rotateRightCentered = AffineTransform.getQuadrantRotateInstance(-1, centerX, centerY);
```

If you like to use radians, yes, it's similar. 90 degrees left is `-(Math.PI / 2)`.