# How to display an image in a frame?

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface, jframe

I am coding a gui and I wanted to use embedde some pictures, but before embedding it in my main program I wrote that code to test it:

```
    public class guikopie extends javax.swing.JFrame{
        public guikopie() {
            a = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            a.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Tulpen.jpg"));       
            add(a);//here i add it to the jlabel
            pack();
        }

        public static void main(String args[]){
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new guikopie().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        private javax.swing.JLabel a;
    }
```

My question is: Why does this code do not display the picture?

Comment: it worked on my computer. check the path of your image please.

Comment: which path did you take?

Comment: "src/icon.png" it was an image in my java source folder.

Comment: btw is there a method to resize the image?

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: "*is there a method to resize the image?*" take a pick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876615/how-do-i-resize-images-inside-an-application-when-the-application-window-is-resi/12876799#12876799 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911610/affinetransform-rotate-how-do-i-xlate-rotate-and-scale-at-the-same-time/11911758#11911758

Comment: Given the way the image is used, it will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource] by the time the app. is deployed.  At that point, using a `String` to `ImageIcon` will not work.  See the tag Wiki for embedded-resource for what will work.

Comment: @maximus : Please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230) for more info and this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230) for clarification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think people may hate me for repeating this :P:

- Dont extend JFrame class
- Class names begin with captial letter i.e `Guikopie`

Also depending on what the background is being used for i.e if its a logo that will be added to a specific location on the `JPanel` then using a `JLabel` is fine, however, if its being used as a background it is not; because it will moved around as more components are being added, thus we should not add the background as a component rather we paint the background on the component.

As for your question:

> My question is: Why does this code do not display the picture?

your code works perfect for me thus the location of your picture must be incorrect.

I did a short example showing how to add a `Image` to `JPanel` background and then add `JPanel` to `JFrame`, it also includes class `ImgUtils` for resizing picture:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JFrameWithPicture {

    public JFrameWithPicture() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new JFrameWithPicture();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void initComponents() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame with JPanel and background");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final Image background = ImageUtils.scaleImage(300, 300, ImageIO.read(new URL("http://images2.layoutsparks.com/1/98191/naruto-14-red-design.jpg")));
        final Dimension jpanelDimensions = new Dimension(new ImageIcon(background).getIconWidth(), new ImageIcon(background).getIconHeight());

        frame.add(new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {
                super.paintComponent(grphcs);
                grphcs.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return jpanelDimensions;
            }
        });

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class ImageUtils {

    public static BufferedImage scaleImage(int width, int height, String filename) {
        BufferedImage bi;
        try {
            ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(filename);
            bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bi.createGraphics();
            g2d.addRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY));
            g2d.drawImage(ii.getImage(), 0, 0, width, height, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
        return bi;
    }

    static Image scaleImage(int width, int height, BufferedImage filename) {
        BufferedImage bi;
        try {
            bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bi.createGraphics();
            g2d.addRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY));
            g2d.drawImage(filename, 0, 0, width, height, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
        return bi;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you may want to resize using [Image#getScaledInstance(int width,int height,int hints)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29), but [this has its perils](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html), the main problem being:

> `Image.getScaledInstance()` does not return a finished, scaled image.
>   It leaves much of the scaling work for a later time when the image
>   pixels are used.

Comment: @Sujay +1 thank you and who can not love naruto and the kyuubi ?! :P

Comment: @DavidKroukamp why to NOT extend JFrame?

Comment: @PrototypeStark 1)you only extend classes to add functionality 2) once you extends `JFrame` you cant extend another class which you may **ACTUALLY** need to

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class guikopie extends javax.swing.JFrame{
    public guikopie() {
        a = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(a);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        a.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Tulips.jpg"));
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new guikopie().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JLabel a;
}
```

Check this code. Your path may be wrong.

Comment: and the problem-solving difference of your snippet to OP's code is ... ?

Comment: @kleopatra correct path? Tulipen.jpg wasn't found and will never be found on my computer(NOT SPANISH)

Comment: that's not a reason to reproduce the whole snippet (including the naming convention violation ...)