# How to fit Image size to JFrame Size?

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a `JPanel` into a `JFrame`. I loaded a picture on the `JPanel` but its shown just a part of the picture: This is the part of the code where i did it:

```
JPanel panelImg = new JPanel()
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Image img = new ImageIcon("Welcome.png").getImage();
        Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setMinimumSize(size);
        setMaximumSize(size);
        setSize(size);
        setLayout(null);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }
};
mainFrame.add(panelImg);
```

So this is how it looks like:

[image: Picture 1]

The complete picture looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to scale the picture to the `JFrame`s size? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at some of these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12660146/1133011 and here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12996718/1133011 they both show how to display and scale images on `JPanel`/`JFrame`. You will just have to scale it now to frame size via `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` (+1 to @trashgod and @MadProgrammer)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, I wouldn't be loading the image inside the `paintComponent` method, this method is call repeatedly (and some times in quick succession), you don't want to do anything that takes time to execute or consumes resources unnecessarily

Check out [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) for suggestions on filling/fitting images to a given area

Comment: Good point about latency; [obligatory example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4530659/230513).

Answer (score 14):

You want the [`drawImage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) that scales to the target container. See the article cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6916719/230513) for alternatives. For example,

```
g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
Image img = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("welcome.png"))
                               .getScaledInstance(WIDTH, HEIGHT, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Its Easy. Follow this example,

```
public class BasePanel extends JPanel {

ImageIcon backImage;
public BasePanel() {
    backImage = new ImageIcon("src/images/welcome.png");
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    BufferedImage scaledImage = getScaledImage();
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(scaledImage, 0, 0, null);
}

private BufferedImage getScaledImage(){
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(getWidth(),getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) image.createGraphics();
    g2d.addRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY));
    g2d.drawImage(backImage.getImage(), 0, 0,getWidth(),getHeight(), null);

    return image;
}

}
```