# How to make images that will re-size when re-sizing a JFrame?

Tags: java, eclipse, image, swing, resize

Hi guys I made a game on java and I want the user to be able to resize the window without the images getting all messed up. Is there a specific method to use for scaling the images along with the JFrame and the components inside the JFrame whic in this case are buttons, labels, panels, etc? BTW. I know how to scale other components but not the images

```
ImageIcon MainLogo = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("/SudokuIcons/MainLogo.png"));
ImageIcon MainLogoMenu2 = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("/SudokuIcons/MainLogoMenu2.png"));
ImageIcon MainLogoMenu3 = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("/SudokuIcons/MainLogoMenu3.png"));
ImageIcon playLogo = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("/SudokuIcons/PlayLogo.png"));
ImageIcon OptionsLogo = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("/SudokuIcons/OptionsLogo.png"));
ImageIcon HelpLogo = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("/SudokuIcons/HelpLogo2.png"));
ImageIcon ExitLogo = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("/SudokuIcons/ExitLogo.png"));
ImageIcon StartGame = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("/SudokuIcons/StartGame.png"));
ImageIcon ChooseDifficulty = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("/SudokuIcons/ChooseDifficulty.png"));
ImageIcon ChooseDifficultyMenu2 = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("/SudokuIcons/ChooseDifficultyMenu2.png"));
ImageIcon GoBackIcon = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("/SudokuIcons/GoBack.png"));
ImageIcon GoBack2Icon = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("/SudokuIcons/GoBack2.png"));
ImageIcon GoBack3Icon = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("/SudokuIcons/GoBack3.png"));
ImageIcon EasyIcon = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("/SudokuIcons/EasySelected1.png"));
ImageIcon MediumIcon = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("/SudokuIcons/MediumSelected1.png"));
ImageIcon HardIcon = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("/SudokuIcons/HardSelected1.png"));
ImageIcon EasyIconSelected = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("/SudokuIcons/EasySelected1.png"));
```

Comment: What did you try? Please show the code

Comment: Im using ImageIcons, Please also know Im a biginner who started programming 2 and a half months ago. My images wont resize as I resize the window, even If I use a base of 4k resolutions. they wont scale down

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fit Image size to JFrame Size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038411/how-to-fit-image-size-to-jframe-size)

Comment: my code runs well, the game runs well, the problem is that if I resize the frame or the window used. the images do not scale together with the window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Darryl's [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/). The Icon will automatically resize to fill the space available to the parent component. You set the scaling to be proportional or just file the entire area.

Comment: Sounds exactly like what I was looking for, Thank you very much. I will give this a try =)