# how to add a background to a jpanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, background, jpanel

I would like to add a jlabel to a jpanel I've used this code

```
JLabel background=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Myimage.jpg"));
panel.add(background);
frame.setContentPane(panel);
```

the image is sized with the minimized window not the maximized one, so when I maximize the window it shows an empty space which I don't want. I would like a background for the jpanel I added

Comment: You’ve described what you don’t want;  now, tell us what you do want.  What should be seen when the window is maximized?  Do you want the image stretched?  Centered?  Tiled (that is, repeated)?

Comment: stretched with the maximized window to fill it, its a background.

Comment: Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted whenever it helped (most) in solving the problem. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just override the `paintComponent(Graphics g) : void` of your JPanel. The following solution will scale your image always to the panel size.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

    private Image image;

    public void setBackgroundImage(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this);
    }
}
```

For performance and quality aspects it could be also useful to set some [RenderingHints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html).For more information see [Controlling Rendering Quality](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/quality.html).

Please consider to search first before you ask. Maybe this answer adresses your problem [How to fit Image size to JFrame Size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038411/how-to-fit-image-size-to-jframe-size) as well?

Comment: The final argument to the drawImage method should be `this`.

Comment: should I use a buffered image or should I use the jlabel?

Comment: The direct way would be to use a `BufferedImage`. But `new ImageIcon('xyz').getImage();` is also possible.

Comment: `g.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), null);` should be `g.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this);`, especially when using `Image` as the actual image data might not have been realised when it was passed to you and when you tried to paint it. Also, you should override the `getPreferredSize` method and return the size of the image at least

Comment: @Lose'CKi `JLabel` will work, but if the required size of the components within ite exceed the size of the image, they will be clipped. `ImageIO.read` is more preferrable then `ImageIcon` for a number of reasons, but manily because it throws an `IOException` when the image can't be loaded instead of failing siliently. `BufferedImage` extends from `Image` so you can use it whereever `Image` can be used