# Java mirror text horizontally (rotate and mirror text in JFrame)

Tags: java, transform

I would like to ask is there any way to mirror the text horizontally like below image:

[image]

Situation:
Currently I have a `JFrame` and create`JLabels` to add texts into `JFrame`.
User can move `JLabel` texts around the `JFrame` window, and program will update position of the text.

Now I want to:

1) rotate the text (90,180,270,360 degrees)

2) mirror the text vertical and horizontally

Comment: What did you try? Show some code.

Comment: So you two basic problems, first you need to be able to convert text to an image, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800717/convert-text-content-to-image/18800845#18800845); next you need to be able to mirror the image for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911610/affinetransform-rotate-how-do-i-xlate-rotate-and-scale-at-the-same-time/11911758#11911758)

Comment: @ShivamPuri: I am asking on the methods to achieve that.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: wow, that's great and that's what I am looking for. Thank you very much for your fast response !